# Best practice for storing an array of struct of undefined length

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

### The question

Let's suppose that we have a `struct` such as:

```
struct MyStruct
{
  enum Type { NONE, TYPE1, TYPE2 };
  Type type;
  int value;
}
```

Now, the application needs to store a undefined amount of these structs on an array or similar.
The question is: Which will be the best way to do this in terms of memory usage, speed, elegance, etc?

### Some considerations

1. To have a fixed length array with a length that you know that is not going to be overtaken:

   ```
   MyStruct myStructArray[200];
   ```

   I suppose this will lead to more memory usage as it will reserve space for the incoming struct instances.
2. To have some autoresizable array mechanism like a `vector<MyStruct>` managing memory by itself.
3. To store pointers to each `struct` in some array or `vector`.

Comment: 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2.

Comment: I personally use 3 and I've never had any problems. But your struct seems really small, I don't think you have to worry about space.

Comment: Can't other than agree with jrok, I'd use `std::vector`. The other solutions are _much_ more error prone (overflow/memory management).

Comment: It totally depend on what you are going to do with it. For an overview of different type containers that will do the memory management for you: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container

Comment: @JosephPla Well, let's say that this is a sample generic struct. I'm looking for a generic answer for any size of struct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::vector<MyStruct>` is the better option. There is also another option, which is very close to vector in some way, is called  `std::deque`. Have a look at it; *maybe* it will help you, or at least increase your awareness of standard containers. The [online doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) says,

> As opposed to `std::vector`, the elements of a deque are not stored contiguously: typical implementations use a sequence of individually allocated fixed-size arrays.
>
> The storage of a deque is automatically expanded and contracted as needed. Expansion of a deque is cheaper than the expansion of a `std::vector` because it does not involve copying of the existing elements to a new memory location.

Although, `std::deque` doesn't store elements in contiguous memory, it works with `RandomAccessIterator` — pretty much like `std::vector`.

Comment: What if the op would like to do a lot of additions, insertions, removal at random loctions?

Comment: @hetepeperfan: there can be lots of what-ifs. What if he doesn't want that?

Comment: then he should specify his/her question better.

Comment: @hetepeperfan: BTW, `std::deque` works with `RandomAccessIterator`.

Comment: not that I disapprove your answer but, unless we know precisly what the original poster want, how can we possibly provide an accurate answer.

Comment: @hetepeperfan: I've answer the *asked* question, not which he didn't ask. The accuracy of an answer depends on the details provided in the question.

Comment: Let's say that there aren't many additions and a few or none removals.
I think @Nawaz answer is good enough to my question.

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::vector<>` if your size can vary during runtime, use `std::array<>` if it is fixed. Although the effort for adding and removing elements in a `std::deque<>` is lower than for a `std::vector<>`, `vector<>` provides data in contiguous memory, which, esp. for linear traversal, is much more cache friendly. This will improve performance compared to containers that rely on btrees or similar that can be distributed in memory leading to cache misses during traversal.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot one possibility: dynamically allocated arrays. You can also do this:

```
long myStructCount = /*whatever*/;
MyStruct* myStructArray = new MyStruct[myStructCount];
```

This is worse that `std::vector<MyStruct>` from a usage perspective, but definitely preferable to that evil `MyStruct myStructArray[200]` approach.

The fixed size approach is evil because there are preciously few cases in which you can *prove* that your limit won't be exceeded, so in most cases it's nothing more or less than a bug waiting to strike.

Comment: As I understand, this possibility is just the 3rd one with the _array_ approach. Also, it doesn't prevent the app from crashing when it exceeds `myStructCount`, so it isn't much different from 1.

Comment: @j4nSolo No, it's not the same as 3., because it uses an array of `MyStruct` instead of an array of `MyStruct*`. Also, even though it is technically possible to exceed myStructCount, it is not possible iff myStructCount is calculated correctly. The point is, that you don't use some arbitrary fixed limit, but the actual amount of space that is _required_. The first is almost always a bug, the second can relatively easily be handled in a bug free way.